# Android InAppPurchase | How should I invalidate linkedPurchaseToken after downgrade or upgrade the SKU?

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api, android-developer-api

I have just implemented **InAppPurchase** functionality for an **Android app** where users can subscribe to a product. And it is working fine along with the validation process. But if the user goes for downgrade or up-gradation then my Google play generating a new Token for that and attached the old token (linkedPurchaseToken). Right!

**linkedPurchaseToken = "null"   ------    again**

So, how can I invalidate that token? Like a newly purchased item has linkedPurchaseToken = "null" if I verify using Cloud Function and for product migration, it has a token. Please help. I'm stuck over here.

Comment: I have a similar problem. If I resubscribe after the subscription expired the linkedpurchasetoken is also null meaning I can't associate the purchase. Did you manage to solve that issue yet?